# All pictures inside my Office 365 word got disappear

Tags: office-365, microsoft-word

I have a word document with 219 pages, and all pages contain one or 2 pictures. the size of the file was above 20 MB . now suddenly when i open it , it size is only 87 KB and all pictures are showing errors as follow "The picture can not be displayed":-

[image]

here is my office version

[image]

and i have this setting already enabled:-

[image]

any advice? where the pictures got lost??